# isinstance not working for Decimal in AppEngine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, sqlalchemy, decimal

I have an instance of `decimal.Decimal` which comes from an SQLAlchemy query. As I need to serialize the object, I have created a JSON serializer to deal with the `Decimal`:

```
import decimal
class AlchemyEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, decimal.Decimal):
            return str(obj)
        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)
```

The unfortunate thing is that the `isinstance(obj, decimal.Decimal)` does not return a `True` for the instance, even though (using pdb in the `default` method above):

```
obj.__class__ # => <class 'decimal.Decimal'>
blah = decimal.Decimal()
blah.__class__ # => <class 'decimal.Decimal'>
isinstance(obj, decimal.Decimal) # => False
isinstance(blah, decimal.Decimal) # => True
isinstance(obj, obj.__class__) # => True
```

I did check that the module both instances refer to is the same module:

```
import inspect
inspect.getfile(obj.__class__) # => '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/decimal.pyc'
inspect.getfile(blah.__class__) # => '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/decimal.pyc'
```

I would really love to understand why this is not working!

**EDIT**

It turns out that the issue only occurs when running under AppEngine's `dev_appserver.py` environment. A simple:

```
isinstance(db.session.execute('SELECT amount FROM model LIMIT 1').fetchone()[0], decimal.Decimal)
```

returns `False` when making a request via the AppEngine dev_appserver and `True` when run from the console.

Comment: What is the result of `obj.__class__ is blah.__class__`?

Comment: @BrenBarn it's `False`

Comment: You seem to have an indentation error in your code ... the `return json.JSONEncoder.default(...)` should probably be in the `default` function.

Comment: @mgilson Cheers, it was - just went wrong when copying it onto SO.

Comment: Any possibility for us to be able to reproduce this strange behavior?

Comment: Yeah, we might need a bit more info. I can't reproduce this with an sqlite db, but sqlite doesn't handle decimal natively, and sqlalchemy has to do the conversion from floating point. Are you using MySQL, PostgreSQL, ...?

Comment: I tried to generate a reproducible piece of code, and in doing so I found the issue only occurs when running under the AppEngine's `dev_appserver.py`.
Not sure how it's doing it, but it seems to be messing with the classes somehow.

Comment: You might be able to work around it by making some sort of dummy query to get a reference to the Decimal class it has somehow imported.

Comment: @BrenBarn Interesting idea, I'll look into that, thanks! For now I added a `if str(obj.__class__) == "<class 'decimal.Decimal'>"` which I'm not proud of.

Still don't get how it would report the same module / file for both instances though, if it's importing a different one somehow...

Comment: @Aert: It is possible if the module is findable in multiple ways through `sys.path`.  See for instance [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4798589/what-could-cause-a-python-module-to-be-imported-twice).  It could be that GAE is doing some troublesome path manipulations.  You could try peeking into `sys.modules` to see if you can see the module in there twice.

Comment: Cheers, I had a peek, in both cases it's there only once (and both cases the same module path)

Comment: Very odd.  I've never used GAE so I don't think I can offer any more specific suggestions.  You would have to hunt through to see where else it's doing the import and how.

Comment: @BrenBarn It is very strange indeed. Thanks, really appreciate your and others' suggestions.

Comment: Why not use `import numbers
 if isinstance(obj, numbers.Number)`?  That checks for other types (int, float, long, complex) as well.

Comment: What is the result of `obj.__class__.__module__`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ran into this today, and came across an old [mailing list post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine-stackoverflow/7-tRlyt31Ic) that discussed this.

Turns out this question has also been addressed [on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30742626) previously as well. Pasting the answer here for ease of access / reduced stackoverflow server load:

---

It appears that the decimal.Decimal class is patched somewhere in the Google App Engine SDK (or the module is reloaded), and this is done between the MySQL conversion library importing decimal and you importing the same.

Luckily, we can work around this by updating MySQL conversion table:

```
from MySQLdb.constants import FIELD_TYPE
from MySQLdb.converters import conversions
import decimal

conversions[FIELD_TYPE.DECIMAL] = conversions[FIELD_TYPE.NEWDECIMAL] = decimal.Decimal
```

That's it; the above code resets the MySQL class and your JSON encoder type check succeeds.

The alternative would be for you to look for the class MySQLdb is using:

```
class DecimalEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, o):
        if isinstance(o, MySQLdb.converters.conversions[MySQLdb.constants.FIELD_TYPE.DECIMAL]):
            return float(o)
        return super(DecimalEncoder, self).default(o)
```

---